# Increase value of time"stamp" based on previous content - string

Tags: python, renpy

Okay, I was really unsure what to title this. I have a game, where I update the time manually, via a variable.
`$ current_hour = "07:00"` for instance

What I want to be able to do, is increase this without having to manually enter a new time every time. Something like this:
`$ current_hour += 1` (I know this of course won't work)

So, I tried as follows:

```
hour = current_hour
current_hour = str(int(hour[:2]+1)+hour[3:])
```

which then, hopefully, would give me 08:00 - but it doesn't work, and I'm a little stumped as to why.
The error I get is `coercing to unicode, need string or buffer, int found`
I thought I took care of that with the declaring as int() and str() respectively, but obviously I didn't. So, I suck at Python - anyone able to help with this?

Comment: Try this `current_hour = str(int(hour[:2])+1)+hour[2:]`. But, it will fail at edge cases i.e when the hour is `12:00` etc. So, better use `Datetime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
current_hour = "12:00"
current_hour = str(int(current_hour[:2])+1)+current_hour[2:]

if len(current_hour)==4:
  current_hour = '0' + current_hour

if int(current_hour[:2]) >= 13:
  current_hour = str(int(current_hour[:2])-12)+current_hour[2:]

if len(current_hour)==4:
  current_hour = '0' + current_hour
```

Comment: This seems to be working, although because of a different problem, the showing of the variable won't update, so I'll need to solve that before I can answer that definitely :)

Comment: You can declare variable as global or share code or ask new question :)

Comment: That other issue was unrelated, and is fixed, so I've given you the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel, and use datetime objects.

```
from datetime import time
current_hour = time(7)
current_hour # datetime.time(7, 0)

def addhour(time, hours):
    return time.replace(hour = (time.hour + hours)%24)

addhour(current_hour, 1) # datetime.time(8, 0)
current_hour.isoformat() # '08:00:00'
```

Comment: Problem with this is that the variables are stored as strings in the Ren'Py game-engine. Maybe there is a way to use it as a datetime-object, I don't know. Your solution works great by itself, but when I try to use datetime with stored variables, it gets messy, fast.